# Graph Isomorphism Algorithm of Vertex Transistive Graphs and other

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, reductions, graph-isomorphism

What are the best known Graph-Isomorphism algorithms for  below graph classes-

1.vertex-transitive,  2. edge-transitive,  3.arc-transitive (or symmetric) 4.distance-transitive.

Are they **GI Complete**?

Provide run-times/time complexity of algorithm, if possible.

**Related post:** This question was asked on [MSE.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393285/graph-isomorphism-algorithm-of-vertex-transistive-graphs-and-other)